# How do I configure Serilog MSSqlServer Sink with a GUID Id column?

Tags: c#, serilog

When writing to the database, Serilog will set a default Id field. But this is an auto-incrementing field，I want to change this field to a Guid SQL Datatype uniqueidentifier. I want to set a default value and Id is primaryKeyColumnName too. How do I have to change my configuration?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images.

Comment: Also please use the correct tags. Your question has nothing to do with c# 6 (even if it was the version of the language you are using, which I doubt). More likely you meant .net 6, for which you can use the tag [tag:.net-core]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.